# Remember auto-play preference in SCM music player

Tags: cookies, audio-player

I was wondering whether script could be added to the below so that the player would remember a users preferences. We want the player to play music on entering the website by default, but a few of us immediately switch it off and there have been some questions about it posed by some users, especially as if you open another page in a new tab the music will immediately begin again.

Here is the code that is in the player module:

```
<!-- SCM Music Player http://scmplayer.net -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scmplayer.net/script.js" 
data-config="{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'placement':'top','showplaylist':false,'playlist':
{'title':'Aldmeri','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukSo-fZYLHk'},
{'title':'Jungles of Elsweyr','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFrD53PWx3M'},
{'title':'Nchuand-Zel','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQQzq97Kazw'},
{'title':'ESO Theme','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOaWH2fp0mA'},
{'title':'Beauty of Dawn','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?        feature=player_embedded&v=zXdbKz5u-a4'}]}" ></script>
<!-- SCM Music Player script end -->
```

I don't know much about coding but is there a way that someone would pause the music and then the next time they visit it will be paused automatically? Not sure if it is possible but thought I would at least try.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I think that a cookie will be the best answer but I really don't know where to start. I have researched the syntax used for cookies, but do not understand how I would have it remember a user's preferences. I don't know if the following information regarding Syntax that is recognised by the music player would also be required as follows:

SCM.play();
Plays the current song.

SCM.pause();
Pause the currently playing song

If someone could help then that would be great as I would really love to make the changes this weekend if at all possible. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole question has nothing to do with version-control.

Comment: I don't know much in web development, but it seems to me that you can store the preference in cookie, and control the "auto-play" of the player by code manually depending on the preference in cookie

Comment: It somehow defaulted to version-control when I typed SCM but I had corrected it as soon as I noticed. My apologies.

I was thinking a cookie, but I don't know the first thing about doing this. It is in an enjin.com website so everything goes into modules. Do you, or anyone else know how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I think a cookie IS the way to go, but I have no idea how to write one for this particular need. If someone could add a cookie to the above code to have it remember the user's setting for autoplay i.e if they pause it, it would stay paused the next time they visit, and even the volume too. I would very much appreciate it. :) I would say the cookie should be active for 30 days.

Comment: go to learn some basics first (e.g. from w3schools.com).  If you have some specific problem, feel free to raise here and I think people are pleased to help.  What you are asking now is simply too broad to answer

Comment: I have been doing A LOT of research, and have some basic HTML experience, but I just can't find anything that would do this and don't have the basis to understand how to dissect the cookie code to understand what would be put into the value section etc. I am not being lazy, but I have spent a lot of time over the last four days searching every resource I could find. From what i understand I could give the cookie any name, but what value would I place there, how do i tell the cookie to remember the user's choice of play or pause and then how would I read the cookie?

Comment: I have seen people here write a few lines of code for another and was really hoping that someone would find it in their hearts to do the same for me if at all possible.
I always try to find answers myself and only ask for minimum input from others but this time I am completely stumped. Saying that, it looks as though a cookie wouldn't take long to write for someone with the correct experience.

Comment: The resource you gave is similar to others which explains cookies well, but the example used is in regards to a user input and remembering that, mine would have to remember the last action fo playing or pausing before the user leaves (as they may pause for a while then play again. I am not sure if the cookie would have to act on the script at http://scmplayer.net/script.js
I understand frustration at people that come here for an easy fix, but I have tried a lot on my own, including seeing if it was possible to add in Dreamweaver, but it is like a foreign language to me.